# Ubuntu 20.04 has problems to wake up from suspend when swap is turned off

Tags: 20.04, suspend, swap

I have a fresh install with dual boot Windows and encrypted home directory and I am running into this problem. Anytime I disable the swap file in  `/etc/fstab` my laptop loses the ability to suspend or to wake up from suspend.

It either fails to suspend - restarting instead, or becomes unresponsive after suspending, or the keyboard is not working.

Has anyone had similar problems? Any idea what can be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not for suspend, but for hibernate Linux uses the swap.
You need to have a swap space activated bigger than the actual RAM memory in use.

Suspend keeps the information in memory at the cost of a small part of battery, I've observed 0.5% to 1% of battery per hour suspended.
Hibernate swaps the memory to the swap space and completely powers off the computer, so it uses 0% of battery.

I believe your computer is attempting to hibernate instead of suspend, or after a while being suspended (this can be setup) it attempts to hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My swap is only 2GB, whereas my RAM is 16GB, and it still works whenever the swap is enabled.

Comment: From those 16GB of RAM how much are in use when you hibernate? If it's less than 2GB should work.

Comment: You're right, whenever I have more than 2 GB RAM used, the suspend blows up.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad to help. :)